Open VSCode within a defined virtualenv
While coding on VSC, I often need to use the terminal within the virtualenv I'm using at the moment.
The problem is: every time I go to "New Terminal", I need to activate the virtualenv I need for that specific session. I normally switch between virtualenvs several times a day, so I am looking for a way to save time.
I must be poorly using VSC features, there must be a better way (profiles? or some extension?) but this is how I am doing it right now:
I have a bash script that activates the virtualenv and then calls VSC. But it doesn't work all the time, I don't know exactly why (sometimes "New Terminal" results in no virtualenv at all, and some other times it is still within the last used virtualenv.
The script (see at the end of the message) is associated with a key and path passed as a parameter. For example, I press CTRL+SHIFT+D to execute a script that activates my daily test environment.
So the question is, is there a simple way to open VSC with a given virtualenv already activated so I don't have to activate it every time I start VSC's "New Terminal"?
Note I do not want to associate a virtualenv to a specific project, file, workspace or repo, but for a session (by this I mean, every time I open VSC I will use it into one specific virtualenv. If I need a different virtualenv, I just close VSC and re-open it with my script below using a different virtualenv).
Edit 0: The script does not work, because it (wrongly) assumes this: if I activate a virtualenv and then call VSC, VSC 'new terminal' will open into the active virtualenv at the time of calling VSC. This is not the case. It doesn't matter if I call VSC from a terminal that just activated the virtualenv or has no virtualenv activated whatsoever. VSC doesn't care/know which virtualenv was activated before calling VSC.
This is the script executed when pressing CTRL+SHIFT+D:
#!/bin/bash
echo --------------------------  virtualenv: daily tests --------------------------
echo "changing to path: $1"
cd $1
echo --------------------------  Activate VirtualEnv --------------------------
echo Activate Virtual Environment at:
echo    /home/user/.virtualenvs/VirtEnvRG001_daily_tests/bin/activate
source /home/user/.virtualenvs/VirtEnvRG001_daily_tests/bin/activate
echo Wait 1 s
sleep 1
echo Calling VSC...
code $1


What are you using VSC for that's session-based? It's built to work per-project/repo (workspace, to be precise), not per-session.

Have you read the docs? Python environments in VS Code. Specifically: "Select and activate an environment ... The selected environment is used by the Python extension for ... opening a terminal ... VS Code automatically activates the selected environment [unless you] add "python.terminal.activateEnvironment": false to your settings.json"

Related: Auto activate virtual environment in Visual Studio Code. You can find other questions by googling "vscode automatically activate venv".

@wjandrea have you read the OP? I do not want to activate the virtualenv for a given folder/workspace. And I am not looking how to automatically activate venv.

Well, I don't understand why you're trying to use VSC like this. Like I said, it's not designed to do that. (That's why I asked that question first.) If you give some background, that can help me understand the underlying problem you're trying to solve. If it helps understand where I'm coming from, check out XY problem.

Hello, does trying to use the described script file get the effect? Or try the method described in the answer to achieve the desired effect?

@wjandrea yes, it may be that I am kind of 'misusing' VSC, and I acknowledge that maybe I need to change my perspective (I'm open to it). The concept of workspace does not work for me. Say you have two very different programming jobs (each one with several projects, folders, etc.) and each job has its own, very different, and non-compatible virtualenv. How would you go about this?

@Jeanneli the script does not work, I added this to the OP.

Don't put a solution in the question; that's what answers are for. I edited it out. If you think White Owl's answer would benefit from any of those details, you can write a comment to suggest them, or go a step further by making a suggested edit. You could even write your own answer if you think it's different enough.

Yes, it is done with terminal profiles.
you would define a profile like:
{
  "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "MyTerminal": {
      "path": "/usr/bin/bash",
      "args": [
         "--init-file",
         "/home/user/.virtualenvs/VirtEnvRG001_daily_tests/bin/activate"
      ]
    }
  },
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "MyTerminal"
}

Add this into your settings.json. And this will force the specified script to run each time a new terminal is opened.

yes! That works. And I can even assign a key combination to it!!

I'm not sure if it's because of my setup or because I'm using a conda env or what, but this didn't work quite right for me. For one thing, my .bashrc didn't get read. Instead I did a bootstrap like this: "args": ["-ic", "micromamba activate my_env; exec bash"]

Thanks to White Owl's answer, I added the profiles into the configuration file and it works now as intended. Now I just open the desired profile into the terminal and don't have to activate the virtualenv each time.
In this case I used two virtualenvs (in Linux): 'daily' and 'geo'.
Below is the exact part I added to settings.json:
"terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
    "Geo": {
        "path": "/usr/bin/bash",
        "args": ["--init-file", "/home/user/.virtualenvs/geo/bin/activate"]
    },
    "Daily": {
        "path": "/usr/bin/bash",
        "args": ["--init-file", "/home/user00/.virtualenvs/daily/bin/activate"]
    }
},
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "Daily"

